# "diff"-ing current with "earlier" time

Tags: vimdiff, undo-redo

I have a file opened and I know I can do `:diffsplit` to open the file in a diff view.

I also know that I can do something like `:earlier 30m` to see how the file was 30 minutes ago.

My question is: how do I combine them and open a diff in a split to see the differences between now and 30 minutes ago?

Comment: the undotree and gundo plugin allows that. Even my old histwin plugin allows that. It can be done manually, but it requires stepping through the undo tree, saving the buffer contents into a variable, restoring the undo state, opening a split window with the old buffer contents and creating a diff of that.

Answer (score 1):

map this to some keybinding -

```
:earlier 1f \| DiffOrig<CR>
```

you will need difforig in your vimrc:

```
if !exists(":DiffOrig")
  command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r ++edit # | 0d_ | diffthis
          \ | wincmd p | diffthis
endif
```